# Cauchy Identity for a specialized product of Schur polynomials

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions, young-tableaux

Let $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_d)$ be a partition, with $|\lambda|=n$. Let $\nu=\nu(\lambda):=(\lambda_1-1,\lambda_2,\cdots,\lambda_d).$ In other words, $\nu$ is obtained from $\lambda$ by removing the right-most box on the first row. Is there a nice formula for:

$\sum_{\lambda \vdash n}s_{\lambda}(\mathbf{x})s_{\nu(\lambda)}(\mathbf{y}),$

where $s_\lambda(\mathbf{x})$ is the corresponding Schur function, and we can assume that the sum is over all $\lambda$ which give a valid partition $\nu(\lambda)$? The usual Cauchy identity that I know doesn't apply here unfortunately since $\nu$ cannot be written as $\lambda\backslash \mu$, for some partition $\mu$. On the other hand, $\nu\subset \lambda$.

Comment: Not every such $v(\lambda)$ is a partition though. What if $\lambda_{1} = \lambda_{2}$? Do you want to be removing the first removable block when you go top to bottom?

Comment: @Siddharth Venkatesh: I've added an edit assuming the sum is over only those partitions where $\nu$ is a valid partition. Thanks for the clarification.